# How do I create a trigger with Inner Joins

Tags: mysql, view, triggers, inner-join

I'm trying to create a trigger to populate an aud Loan Table when there is an insert in the Loan table. I want this aud Table to have data from both the Loan table and another table, so I'm trying to set variables that get this data.

When creating the trigger I'm getting the error "Unknown system variable 'var1'"

This is the database layout:

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/582912082450710528/583696750322253824/unknown.png

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER Loan_Insert AFTER INSERT ON loan
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

SET var1 =
(SELECT loan_type.type_of_loan
FROM loan INNER JOIN loan_type ON
loan.loan_type_idloan_type = loan_type.idloan_type
AND
loan.loan_type_idapp_type = loan_type.idapp_type
WHERE loan.loan_type_idloan_type = new.loan_type_idloan_type
AND loan.loan_type_idapp_type = new.loan_type_idapp_type);

SET var2 =
(SELECT loan_type.app_type
FROM loan INNER JOIN loan_type ON
loan.loan_type_idloan_type = loan_type.idloan_type
AND
loan.loan_type_idapp_type = loan_type.idapp_type
WHERE loan.loan_type_idloan_type = new.loan_type_idloan_type
AND loan.loan_type_idapp_type = new.loan_type_idapp_type);


INSERT INTO Aud_Loan(bk_Loan, type_of_loan, type_of_loan_description, application_type,
application_type_description, insert_date)
VALUES(new.idloan, new.loan_type_idloan_type, var1, new.loan_type_idapp_type, var2,CURDATE());
END $$
```

Comment: You need to DECLARE variables.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I forgot about that. I declared the variables by adding @ before their name. And that allowed me to create the trigger. I'm now getting an error when I try to insert a row in the Table the trigger is set to, which is "Subquery returns more than 1 row", and I believe it is related to my trigger. Do you know what the problem might be?

Comment: The queries used to retrieve values for var1 and or var2 are likely returning multiple results; you need to determine an appropriate way to get a single result. (LIMIT 1 would work, but if you're getting back multiple rows, you should probably double check your logic to make sure you are getting using the correct one.)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly it!
My problem now is that it is getting the values twice, because there are 2 loans with the same loan_type and app_type. But I was expecting to get it only once. I've tried all types of join (INNER,LEFT,RIGHT...) and it doesn't work

Comment: It looks like you don't actually need those queries to reference `loan` and join to `loan_type`; you should be able to select directly from `loan_type` using your `new.` values.

Comment: how could I get those 2 values then?
Sorry, I really have no clue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Local variables must be `DECLARE`d. [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare-local-variable.html)
- When using SET, the right hand side must only return one value (single result with single field).

In you particular case, you can probably tweak the queries used in your SET statements like this:

```
SET var1 = (
   SELECT loan_type.type_of_loan
   FROM loan_type 
   WHERE loan_type.idloan_type = NEW.loan_type_idloan_type
      AND loan_type.idapp_type = NEW.loan_type_idapp_type
);
```

and you can probably even reduce it to one query with [SELECT INTO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html):

```
SELECT loan_type.type_of_loan, loan_type.app_type
INTO var1, var2
FROM loan_type 
WHERE loan_type.idloan_type = NEW.loan_type_idloan_type
   AND loan_type.idapp_type = NEW.loan_type_idapp_type
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that does help, but I'm still getting several values with that select (because there are 2 loans with the same loantype and apptype). I think I can solve that problem by using a "SELECT DISTINCT". Is there any better way?

Comment: That select should only give multiple results if the is more than one loan_**type** with those values; (Edit: the second one had a transcription error that put the AND outside the query... that might have caused an issue if you left that condition out, if multiple loan_types have the same idloan_type value.)

Comment: Thank you, that does work wonderfully!

I'm just curious, how can I make it work with INNER JOIN? (for the case where I want to go to further tables).

I tried doing it like this:

```sql
SELECT loan_type.type_of_loan
FROM loan_type INNER JOIN loan ON
loan.loan_type_idloan_type = loan_type.idloan_type
 AND loan.loan_type_idapp_type = loan_type.idapp_type
WHERE loan.loan_type_idloan_type = 9
 AND loan.loan_type_idapp_type = 1
```

But it returns multiple values

Comment: You get multiple results because you cannot uniquely identify the specific `loan` records with those values; if `loan` has a primary key value, it is best to use that instead of values that may be shared by other loans.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.

Adding a "DISTINCT" to the select also works (as all of the values will be the same).

Thank you very much for the input

Comment: DISTINCT works in this case, because all loans matching that criteria link back to the same loan_type; but if this were an AFTER UPDATE trigger and you were trying to find the most recent entry from something like a loan_transaction table, identifying the precise loan would be crucial.